# How to order file names "00.png" and "001.png"? Which goes first?

Tags: binary, sequence, numeric

There is a gallery in which there are 2 files (.png): One of them is signed as "00.png" and another one "001.png". Which of these photos will go first and why?

Comment: I already understood that the question was asked incorrectly. Sorry. I'll try differently. There is a gallery in which there are 2 files (.png): One of them is signed as "00.png" and another one "001.png". Which of these photos will go first and why? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about how these should be ordered lexigographically?

Comment: According to the numbering in the file's signature, what number will the computer put in first place? Or does it depend on the programming language?

Comment: File names will be ordered as strings inside applications such as windows explorer if you sort by name. In general the sort order will depend on Windows api and collation rules in that case.

Comment: I talk about "website photo gallery", not Windows. In this case, it depends on the programming language on which this gallery was created?